# 2 arrays into 1, with lambda exp distinct

Tags: c#, lambda

I've got 2 object arrays that Im getting from the DB, some overlap, so I have to make a distinct func.

I tried to make a lambda expression , but I still got an overlapped objects.

this is my code:

```
ArtObject[] pinui = new ArtObject[root.Count - 1];
ArtObject[] c1=     new ArtObject[root2.Count - 1];

pinui = getArticlesArray(root2, pinui);
c1= getArticlesArray(root, c1);

art = new ArtObject[c1.Count()+pinui.Count()];

pinui.CopyTo(art, 0);
c1.CopyTo(art, pinui.Count());

art = art.Distinct().OrderByDescending(a => a.dateTosort).ToArray();
```

I guess something wrong with my last line, `art = art.Distinct().OrderByDescending(a => a.dateTosort).ToArray();` .. I wonder what and how can I get only the distinct objects..?

Comment: Which field you need to distinct?

Comment: @CuongLe ArtObject descreption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do distinct on one of fields, you can use `GroupBy` then get `First`:

```
pinui.Concat(c1).GroupBy(a => a.Description, (key, g) => g.First())
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.dateTosort).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

`Distinct` will use `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to determine equal values. I suspect you haven't overridden these methods to indicate how you want equality to be checked.

Also note that your last part would be simpler as:

```
ArtObject[] art = pinui.Union(c1).OrderByDescending(a => a.dateTosort).ToArray();
```

`a.Union(b)` is equivalent to `a.Concat(b).Distinct()`.

An alternative to overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` is to specify an `IEqualityComparer<Person>` to either `Union` or `Distinct`.

[MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) makes this easier with a [`DistinctBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method:

```
var query = collection.DistinctBy(x => x.Description);
```

(There's no equivalent for `Union` yet, but we could easliy add one.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine, although it could be shortened (no need to use CopyTo):

```
 var art = pinui.Union(c1).OrderByDescending(a => a.dateTosort).ToArray();
```

`Union` already removes duplicates like `Distinct`.

The reason why the objects are not detected as duplicates is probably because they are distinct. For example, by default,

```
 var obj1 = new ArtObject("Picasso");
 var obj2 = new ArtObject("Picasso");
```

are two distinct objects.

You can, however, [provide a custom equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) to `Distinct` or `Union`, the linked MSDN page contains a nice example.